# Pandas count over groups

Tags: python, pandas, count, group-by, cumsum

I have a pandas dataframe that looks as follows:

```
ID  round   player1     player2 
1   1       A           B           
1   2       A           C
1   3       B           D
2   1       B           C           
2   2       C           D
2   3       C           E
3   1       B           C           
3   2       C           D
3   3       C           A
```

The dataframe contains sport match results, where the `ID` column denotes one tournament, the `round` column denotes the round for each tournament, and `player1` and `player2` columns contain the names of players that played against eachother in the respective `round`.

I now want to cumulatively count the tournament participations for, say, player `A`. In pseudocode this means: If the player with name `A` comes up in either the `player1` or `player2` column per tournament `ID`, increment the counter by 1.

The result should look like this (note: in my example player `A` did participate in tournaments with the `ID`s 1 and 3):

```
ID  round   player1     player2     playerAparticipated
1   1       A           B           1
1   2       A           C           1
1   3       B           D           1
2   1       B           C           0
2   2       C           D           0
2   3       C           E           0
3   1       B           C           2
3   2       C           D           2
3   3       C           A           2
```

My current status is, that I added a "helper" column containing the values `1` or `0` denoting, if the respective player participated in the tournament:

```
ID  round   player1     player2     helper
1   1       A           B           1
1   2       A           C           1
1   3       B           D           1
2   1       B           C           0
2   2       C           D           0
2   3       C           E           0
3   1       B           C           1
3   2       C           D           1
3   3       C           A           1
```

I think that I just need one final step, e.g., a smart use of `cumsum()` that counts the `helper` column in the desired way. However, I could not come up with the solution yet.

Comment: Do you need the values inside the dataframe? `len(df[(df.player1 == 'A') | (df.player2 == 'A')].groupby('ID').count())` would give you the number of tournaments Player 'A' participated.

Comment: yes, I would prefer to have the values in the original dataframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need:

- [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by column `ID` first and then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)
- filter out `0` values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and last [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for add `0` for missing index values
- new column create by [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)

---

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates('ID').set_index('ID')
s = df1.loc[df1['helper'] != 0, 'helper'].cumsum().reindex(index=df1.index, fill_value=0)
df['playerAparticipated'] = df['ID'].map(s)
print (df)
   ID  round player1 player2  helper  playerAparticipated
0   1      1       A       B       1                    1
1   1      2       A       C       1                    1
2   1      3       B       D       1                    1
3   2      1       B       C       0                    0
4   2      2       C       D       0                    0
5   2      3       C       E       0                    0
6   3      1       B       C       1                    2
7   3      2       C       D       1                    2
8   3      3       C       A       1                    2
```

Instead `map` is possible use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with `rename`:

```
df = df.join(s.rename('playerAparticipated'), on='ID')
print (df)
   ID  round player1 player2  helper  playerAparticipated
0   1      1       A       B       1                    1
1   1      2       A       C       1                    1
2   1      3       B       D       1                    1
3   2      1       B       C       0                    0
4   2      2       C       D       0                    0
5   2      3       C       E       0                    0
6   3      1       B       C       1                    2
7   3      2       C       D       1                    2
8   3      3       C       A       1                    2
```

Comment: Really like this use of reindex & map

Comment: one question related to your answer: why exactly is `set_index` needed? what is the purpose?

Comment: In my solution it let column untouched by creating `index` - because need process `helper` column

Answer (score 1):

A similar approach to @jezrael that I cooked up a little slower :).

First, move `ID` into your index:

```
df = df.reset_index().set_index(['index','ID'])
#          round player1 player2  helper
# index ID
# 0     1       1       A       B       1
# 1     1       2       A       C       1
# 2     1       3       B       D       1
# 3     2       1       B       C       0
# 4     2       2       C       D       0
# 5     2       3       C       E       0
# 6     3       1       B       C       1
# 7     3       2       C       D       1
# 8     3       3       C       A       1
```

Next, filter out rows where `helper` is 0 and get a cumulative sum of tournaments by `ID`, and assign the result to a variable:

```
tournament_count = df[df['helper'] > 0].groupby(['ID','helper']).first().reset_index(level=1)['helper'].cumsum().rename("playerAparticipated")
# ID
# 1    1
# 3    2
```

Finally, join the `tournament_count` DataFrame with df:

```
df.join(tournament_counts, how="left").fillna(0)
#          round player1 player2  helper  tournament_counts
# index ID
# 0     1       1       A       B       1                1.0
# 1     1       2       A       C       1                1.0
# 2     1       3       B       D       1                1.0
# 3     2       1       B       C       0                0.0
# 4     2       2       C       D       0                0.0
# 5     2       3       C       E       0                0.0
# 6     3       1       B       C       1                2.0
# 7     3       2       C       D       1                2.0
# 8     3       3       C       A       1                2.0
```