# Pandas better way of counting groups within a group?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I saw a couple of related questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45119623/pandas-count-over-groups), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837754/count-each-group-sequentially-pandas), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880388/unique-values-within-pandas-group-of-groups)), but they don't produce the output that I'm looking for. I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['USA','USA','Canada','Canada'],
                   'City': ['Los Angeles','NYC','Toronto','Toronto'],
                   'Value': [100,200,300,400]})
df

  country city        value
0 USA     Los Angeles 100
1 USA     NYC         200
2 Canada  Toronto     300
3 Canada  Toronto     400
```

And I want to count the number of unique cities for each country. I'm currently doing this:

```
df.groupby('country').city.unique().apply(len)
Country
Canada  1
USA     2
```

Is this a reasonable way, or is there something better? Thank you.

Comment: `df.groupby('Country')['City'].nunique()`

Comment: Thanks y'all, sorry I couldn't find those other duplicate questions.

Comment: Should I delete this post then?

Comment: its upto you :) and no worries